# Sorted @variable in Controller doesn't resort after adding a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have something along the lines of:

```
@events = Event.all.sort_by{ |each| [each.date] }.reverse.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
```

After I add an event to database I see it appears last in index even though the date should put it first or among the first.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is any reason to use a custom sort_by instead of the ordering helper Rails give you, so I suggest you to use this instead:

```
@events = Event.all.order(date: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 7)
```

This will order them by the event date using the provide helpers. You could change it to 'date: :asc' to reverse the order.